# Generate PDF in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, pdf-generation, laravel-5.1

What is the best library in Laravel 5.1 for generating PDF with style and image?. I have used dompdf once. Although it works on localhost without style and image, But it does not work on live server.

Anyone please share your experience about generating PDF with style and image in Laravel 5.1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you not tried Snappy Check it out [Here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate pdf by using dompdf package. but make sure all css should inline or onpage.